# Matlab Imshow Ubuntu Parallels Mac

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-14.04, imshow

I have this problem with matlab running on my MacOs Parallels Ubuntu 14.04: when I enter `imshow(a,[])` matlab returns this error:

> Error using axes
>   While setting the 'Parent' property of 'Axes':
>   Can't reload '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwosgserver.so'

Error in imshow (line 267)
      ax_handle = axes('Parent', fig_handle);

I'm using Matlab R2015b. And if I go the /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/
I can locate the libmwosgserver.so and I've also added it to my LD Library path in the .bashrc file like this: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64:
Please, help me solving this issue.

Comment: Just to confirm - you're running Mac OS and Ubuntu 14.04 on separate partitions on your Mac computer, and you're getting this error when in Ubuntu? I use Windows and Ubuntu and just want to confirm Parallels is the same as "dual booting".

Comment: Also, can you give a little more context than just imshow(a, [])? I'd like to try to replicate your error.

Comment: yes of course: I'm running parallels Ubuntu 14.04 on my Mac Os X El Capitan. I'm running Matlab on the Ubuntu partition and it gives me this error. @jschabs: It is an error that Matlab gives me on whatever image. It is a problem related to the imshow on whatever image.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a reason you're using `imshow(a, [])` and not just `imshow(a)`? Do you get the same error using `imshow(a)`?